# how to invoke object.apply with single implicit parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm trying to do something like this

```scala
case class Foo(p: Param)

object Bar {
  def apply(implicit p: Param) = Foo(p)
}

def qux(implicit p: Param) {
  .. something
  val foo: Foo = Bar
  .. use foo
}
```

what I've reached so far is

```scala
object Bar {
  def apply()(implicit p: Param) = Foo(p)
}

def ... {
  val foo: Foo = Bar()
}
```

Can I do this without parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without parenthesis...

```
case class Foo(p: Param)

object Bar {
  def apply(implicit p: Param) = Foo(p)
}

def qux(implicit p: Param) {
  // .. something
  val foo: Foo = Bar.apply // the only change is here!
  // .. use foo
}
```

... but with an explicit `apply` call, which have the advantage to not change your original signature.

Hope it helps.